# XML tag colors in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, color-scheme

I can't find any according item in VS2010 color settings to change "<" and "/>" elements color.

Give me a tip how to change that element's default color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > XML Delimeter is what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe it's a VS2010 specific thing but it doesn't work. Color remains default.

Comment: Strange. Works in both 2005 and 2008.